# IIS 6 - protect static files (www and without www)

Tags: .net, web-config

We have ASP.Net application on IIS 6. It is hosted on some server I do not have an access. We want that our static files (*.html, *.htm) that sits in help folder to be protected (authentication is necessary for them, so we need that html and htm files are treated as aspx files).

I have found an article here - http://forums.asp.net/t/1184547.aspx (IIS problems with forms authentication & HTML pages). Then I wrote to hosting company and they created html and htm file mapping for IIS 6. Secondly, I configured my web.config file as it was written in article above. As the result links like https://www.mypage.com/help/static.html are protected (user is redirected to login page).

However, links like https://mypage.com/help/static.html are not protected (user is not redirected to login page). I have not found any similar problem on the web.

1) I wonder, what can cause this problem? Is it something with incorrect IIS 6 configuration or I should change my web.config?

2) I wrote to hosting service, they suggested me to read about URLRewriting. I do not feel that this is something about UrlRewriting, or is it? I do not use any url rewriting for now, should I?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are the host is resolving your site via host headers, and explicitly looks for the longer URL, even though the mypage.com URL resolves. The latter isn't caught as a protected reference, so it bypasses their checks. What you can do, however, is to write a chunk of code that checks the inbound URL requested, and if you see the "short" version, redirect the URL to the full name that should, then, get the proper authentication/routing you're wanting. You can even configure basic rewriting in your web.config file.

There's a pretty decent summary of the topic at [this location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx). You might find the web.config example to be the best first-choice to try in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

IIS6 works differently to IIS7; under IIS6 the `web.config` file only controls how ASP.NET works and not IIS, whereas in IIS7 you have the `<system.webServer>` element to configure how IIS is configured.

Secondly, IIS7 (by default) invokes a "Managed Pipeline" which effectively allows ASP.NET to modify every aspect of any incoming HTTP request, which is how ASP.NET URL Routing works (because the Routing HTTP module inspects every incoming HTTP request, if it doesn't match an existing resource then your ASP.NET application handles it).

With respect to your actual problem we need more details. It sounds like your host has two virtual websites created (one handling "www.mysite.com" and another for "mysite.com", and the protection only applies to the "www" site). An alternate explanation is the rule that protects the files checks only if the host-header is "www.mysite.com" instead of also accepting "mysite.com" (or any other host-header for that matter).

URL Rewriting will not help you here. If your host suggested that then it tells me that they might not know what they're doing (also, IIS6 does not support URL rewriting without a third-party extension).